# CDM324 module IF output not showing any signa;when connected to oscilloscope with and without the amplifier circuit

Tags: signals

I recently started working on CDM324 microwave module and when connected it to test the functionality I powered it with 5votls and noticed that the current consumption is around 100-110mA which is way more than the Max supply current i.e., 40mA max mentioned in the datasheet.

when I connected it to oscilloscope the IF output was constant I and even when the object is moved close to the module there was no changes in the IF output.
I designed a 2 stage amplifier with gain of 100 even when connected to it the output was same there was no change in the IF output.

Can anyone please answer this??